# How do I tie up appDelegate to the rest of the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am a relative beginner to iOS development, but I managed to get my app to do everything I want it to. However, I have some questions about tying the app up together.

The only code I have currently inside my appDelegate handles remote notifications; when I receive a remote notification I send out the alerts, messages, and so on to the user. I also generate notifications for the notification center which cause different methods to run inside different view controllers.

What about all the different functions in the appDelegate? DidEnterBackground, WillEnterForeground, etc.? My app starts on one view (view1), which creates an object (stream1), which has a method stopStream. I have buttons to start and stop the streams ([self.stream1 stopStream]). My question in, how do I call these methods to stop that particular instance of the object in one of the appDelegate methods? Do I need to create a notification for the notification center inside the appDelegate, and handle it triggering in the view? Or is there a simpler method? Or am I doing things completely wrong and not according to best practices?

Any help would be appreciated! Also a link to a guide about the architecture of apps, or a link to your favorite book about building apps in iOS would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app delegate only needs to implement the various app delegate methods if the app delegate actually needs to do something with those events.

If a given view controller or other class is interested in the various app delegate notifications (such as enter background, or return to foreground, etc.), then the view controller or other class should register for the corresponding notification. See the docs for `UIApplication` for the different notifications.

Do not have the app delegate method post a custom notification.

Comment: so the appDelegate posts a notification when its various methods are called? interesting; i will look for the documentation!

Comment: No, that's not what I said. For example, when the app returns to the foreground, the OS does two independent things. 1) It calls the `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method on the app delegate, if implemented. 2) It posts the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. Any class that registers for this notification will get notified.

Answer (score 0):

All the methods you're looking for can be found listed [here in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

As for what to do about them thats definitely up to your app. It is best practice to handle at least going in and out of the background properly so at least use the methods for those and take the appropriate action in your app.

Its very common for apps to simply blast out NSNotifications like you mention. Its perfectly acceptable in most circumstances.